# On the eventually regular monoids and generally regular monoids

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Planning the problem:

First we give some definitions.

An element $s \in S$ is called  eventually regular if for every $s \in S$ there exist a natural number $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and $x 
\in S$ such that $s^n = s^n x s^n$. A monoid $S$ is called eventually regular monoid if every $s \in S$ is an eventually regular.

An element $s$ in $S$ is called  generally regular if for every $s \in S$ there exist a natural number $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and $x$ in $S$ such that $s^n = s^n x s$. A monoid $S$ is called generally regular monoid if and only if every $s$ in $S$ is generally regular.

Question:

We know that every eventually regular monoid is generally regular monoid. What can we say about the converse? Is it true to say that a generally regular monoid is an eventually regular monoid?